# Universal Analytics could not track transaction in magento

Tags: javascript, magento, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I'm using magento C.E 1.7. Recently I migrated to universal analytics from google analytics.

After migration, except transaction data, other details are tracked fine.

I have added the following script in head.phtml for universal analytics.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-2', 'mysite.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview'); 
  ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
  ga('ecommerce:send'); 


</script>
```

In admin side too, I have saved the universal analytics tracking code.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I track transaction data? Can anyone help on this?

Comment: There is no transaction or product data in your post. You can look in the documentation (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce) to see what this is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hi I have the same problem today I have written a solution but first remove the custom script in your head.phtml...

---

### First add the ga.phtml

You need to create new file in your template folder or edit the default one:

```
MAGENTOROOT/app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/template/googleanalytics/ga.phtml
```

And add this in the file which will override the base/default Magento ga.phtml

```
<?php if (!Mage::helper('core/cookie')->isUserNotAllowSaveCookie()): ?>
<?php $accountId = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_ACCOUNT) ?>
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODEs -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    <?php echo $this->_getPageTrackingCode($accountId) ?>
    <?php echo $this->_getOrdersTrackingCode() ?>
//]]>
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

### Overide the Default GoogleAnalytics Block

This is not the best way to do it but for simplicity I will use this *if you want more clean solution you need to create module and add the rewrite code there*.

Ok first copy the content of this file:

```
MAGENTOROOT/app/code/core/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/Block/Ga.php
```

and create new file in code/local which will override the code/core one:

```
MAGENTOROOT/app/code/local/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/Block/Ga.php
```

In the new file that you have created modify this two functions to match this code:

**_getPageTrackingCode($accountId)**

```
protected function _getPageTrackingCode($accountId)
{
    $pageName   = trim($this->getPageName());
    $optPageURL = '';
    if ($pageName && preg_match('/^\/.*/i', $pageName)) {
        $optPageURL = ", '{$this->jsQuoteEscape($pageName)}'";
    }
    // if you can think of better way to get the host name
    // let me know in the comments.
    $hostName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    return "
        ga('create', '".$this->jsQuoteEscape($accountId)."', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview' ".$optPageURL.");
    ";
}
```

**_getOrdersTrackingCode()**

```
protected function _getOrdersTrackingCode()
{
    $orderIds = $this->getOrderIds();
    if (empty($orderIds) || !is_array($orderIds)) {
        return;
    }
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $orderIds))
    ;
    $result = array("
        // Transaction code...
        ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
    ");

    foreach ($collection as $order) {
        if ($order->getIsVirtual()) {
            $address = $order->getBillingAddress();
        } else {
            $address = $order->getShippingAddress();
        }

        $result[] = "
            ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
                id:          '".$order->getIncrementId()."', // Transaction ID
                affiliation: '".$this->jsQuoteEscape(Mage::app()->getStore()->getFrontendName())."', // Affiliation or store name
                revenue:     '".$order->getBaseGrandTotal()."', // Grand Total
                shipping:    '".$order->getBaseShippingAmount()."', // Shipping cost
                tax:         '".$order->getBaseTaxAmount()."', // Tax

            });
        ";

        foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {

            $result[] = "
            ga('ecommerce:addItem', {

                id:       '".$order->getIncrementId()."', // Transaction ID.
                sku:      '".$this->jsQuoteEscape($item->getSku())."', // SKU/code.
                name:     '".$this->jsQuoteEscape($item->getName())."', // Product name.
                category: '', // Category or variation. there is no 'category' defined for the order item
                price:    '".$item->getBasePrice()."', // Unit price.
                quantity: '".$item->getQtyOrdered()."' // Quantity.

            });
        ";

        }
        $result[] = "ga('ecommerce:send');";
    }
    return implode("\n", $result);
}
```

Comment: And then use the magento admin panel to add the tracking code in : System > Configuration > Sales | Google API | Google Analytics

Comment: Excellent answer! Congratulations! 
Just one question: Isn't there required also an update in the GoogleAnalytics/Model/Observer.php ?
The method injectAnalyticsInGoogleCheckoutLink is still using the old _gaq.push functions from the old ga.js

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks for sharing :)! Worked like a charm.
I needed GA Universal to add multiple tracking (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400?hl=en) to my Magento website, had to hack the code a little bit but it worked just fine.

Comment: @Dragos yes that would need to be changed but is only needed if you are using Google Checkout for processing payments.

Comment: This was very useful. For those of us still using Magento 1.3.x I adapted this code into the older Magento core module code to update the analytics code to Universal for Magento 1.3.x too. https://github.com/gaiterjones/magento-google-universal-analytics

Comment: I posted a note below on how to correctly set cookie domain.

Comment: I have 2 stroes, one is using google analytics and the other one is universal analytics. I have overrided the class Ga.php and added the functions as _getOrdersTrackingCodeUniversal() and _getPageTrackingCodeUniversal($accountId) with the above said universal analytics code.  I have implemented your code ga.phtml in the stores theme folder and called the above mentioned functions. The page tracking code is working when i saw in view source.  But my orders are not tracked in google analytics.  Kindly tell us what is wrong in my implementation?

Comment: Hi alamelu for which store you are not seeing the orders for the one whit universal analytics or the one whit the default analytics?

Comment: Hi @alamelu have you set E-commerce to on on your analytics property see this link support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009612?hl=en-GB

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note on Daniel's answer that cookie domain is not getting set correctly.

Change this line:

```
ga('create', '".$this->jsQuoteEscape($accountId)."', '".$hostName."');
```

To:

```
ga('create', '".$this->jsQuoteEscape($accountId)."', {'cookieDomain':'".Mage::getStoreConfig('web/cookie/cookie_domain', Mage::app()->getStore() )."'});
```

It inserts the cookie domain correctly from your Magento config versus using the $hostName value which is not set and results in empty ''.

If you're using a CDN on a subdomain this becomes more important to save on that cookie traffic.

Comment: Hi JaseC thanks for your input but for some reason the var_dump(Mage::getStoreConfig('web/cookie/cookie_domain', Mage::app()->getStore() )) returns string(0) "" which version of magento you are using?

Comment: I think much clean will be whit $hostName = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Then I installed the extension below and now it's all working great.
https://magento.mdnsolutions.com/extensions/mdn-google-universal-analytics.html

Hope it can help.

Comment: That is a dead link.

Comment: @Jon the links has been fixed. Cheers!